# File manager not shows my current theme

Tags: gnome, themes, filemanager, personalization

I downloaded a theme for GNOME, it displays everywhere, but when i start the file manager it shows only once, when i quit off the file manager and open it again it disappear, i already change the theme 3 times and the error continues, it's not a theme error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilXat.jpg)

As you can see, my theme is everywhere, only my file manager has problem to process it (The theme not supported GTK4)
But i already try differents GTK4 and GTK3 themes

Help please...:(

Comment: No, i mean the problem was not the themes